# How to delete oracle trace and audit logs from AWS RDS?

Tags: oracle, amazon-rds, oracle12c

I need to delete all the audit and trace logs, one day before, from AWWS RDS oracle 12c.
But in the logs sections of RDS, still showing same count.

I tried these [queries](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=234280) but not working.

My SQL command history below:

```
EXEC rdsadmin.manage_tracefiles.purge_tracefiles('alert_ORCL.log.2021-02-15');
exec rdsadmin.manage_tracefiles.purge_tracefiles(60);
exec rdsadmin.manage_auditfiles.purge_auditfiles(60);
exec rdsadmin.rdsadmin_master_util.drop_archivelog_dir;

SELECT * FROM table(rdsadmin.rds_file_util.listdir('BDUMP')) 

select nvl(sum(BLOCKS * BLOCK_SIZE),0)/1024/1024/1024 GB from V$ARCHIVED_LOG  where DEST_ID=1 and ARCHIVED='YES' and DELETED='NO';
select * from V$ARCHIVED_LOG  where DEST_ID=1 and ARCHIVED='YES' and DELETED='NO';

set serveroutput on
exec rdsadmin.rdsadmin_util.show_configuration;

begin
  dbms_audit_mgmt.set_last_archive_timestamp (
    audit_trail_type => dbms_audit_mgmt.audit_trail_xml,
    last_archive_time => sysdate
  );
end;
/ 
 
select * from dba_audit_mgmt_last_arch_ts;
 
begin
  dbms_audit_mgmt.clean_audit_trail (
    audit_trail_type => dbms_audit_mgmt.audit_trail_xml,
    use_last_arch_timestamp => true
  );
end;
/
```

Any suggestions please.

Tried [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58540453/how-to-delete-archive-log-files-on-aws-rds-oracle-instance) also

Comment: Did you check afterwards on the DB if these files are still available? See: [Listing files](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_LogAccess.Concepts.Oracle.html#USER_LogAccess.Concepts.Oracle.WorkingWithTracefiles)

Comment: yes, not deleted

Comment: Tried truncate table sys.audit$; but getting insufficient privileges error. https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/2170439/purge-audit-trail

Comment: I was going to ask you the question below (later in this comment). Then I am seeing your "Insufficient privileges" error and I am saying to myself, "thank God!" My question was going to be: sorry for being so blunt, but ***why*** do you need to delete audit and trace logs? That sounds very much like something that one shouldn't be allowed to do. Moreover, even when audit logs may be deleted for justifiable reasons, the job is done by someone who knows what they are doing - not by someone who has to ask about it on Stack Overflow. I hope people will not help you without asking such questions.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because I believe we need to understand ***why*** the poster wants to do this. Deleting auditing information shouldn't generally be permitted (and when done, it would be done by someone who already knows how to do it).

Comment: @mathguy I understand where you're coming from and I had the same impulse at first. I'm having a hard time trying to envision a use case where this is a good idea. I am however not sure if we should close a question because of that. If a DBA is looking for this information, shouldn't they be able to find an answer on stackoverflow? I think an answer with a *Do not try this at home* disclaimer could be useful.

Comment: @udaykiran - Please also include the output of the commands you have tried so far, this helps us understand why they failed.

Comment: @Maurice - Reasonable people may disagree, this is why closing a question requires three votes. If three people with enough privileges to close agree that the question should be closed, that's enough for me. The question can be re-opened after the OP explains WHY he needs to do this. Also, as I said - a DBA who needs to do this should be proficient in their job and not learn how to clean up audit info on SO. And the OP clearly is not the DBA - DBA's don't get "insufficient privileges" errors.

Comment: This is a test database server so we want to clear the audit and trace logs as the storage plan we selected is smaller one. And this is database is hosted on AWS using RDS service and I logged in with the admin account, so don't know why it is still showing Insufficient access. As it is a test database server, I hope it doesn't effect your company standards to our test server.

Answer (score 0):

"insufficient privileges" legitimately appears from time to time during learning. It is not necessarily an indication that the user is about to do something harmful or nefarious. In this case, the user is simply trying to work out how do do an unfamiliar task and control AWS costs task on a test system. Truncate table sys.audit$ is an acceptable method in some situations, but it only works as SYS. In RDS, you do not have direct access to SYS and that is why "insufficient privileges" appears.

Comment: To truncate the Oracle RDS audit table, exec rdsadmin.rdsadmin_master_util.truncate_sys_aud_table;. Refer to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71907115/3880849

Answer (score 0):

Check the number and maximum age of your audit files.

```
set linesize 80
set trimspool on
select
count(*) num_files,
round(sum(filesize)/1024/1024) mb,
round(sysdate - min(mtime),4) days
from table(
    rdsadmin.rds_file_util.listdir(
    'ADUMP'
    )
)
where type = 'file'
and filename like '%.aud'
;

quit


 NUM_FILES         MB       DAYS
---------- ---------- ----------
      5856         58     7.0031
```

Then run:

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> exec rdsadmin.rdsadmin_util.set_configuration('tracefile retention', 0);
SQL> exec rdsadmin.manage_tracefiles.purge_tracefiles(0);
```

Then wait for 5 minutes and check:

```
 NUM_FILES         MB       DAYS
---------- ---------- ----------
         5          0      .0005
```