# How do I truncate the Oracle audit table in AWS RDS?

Tags: oracle, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, truncate, audit

How do I truncate the Oracle audit table in Amazon AWS RDS?

```
SQL> select count(*) from sys.aud$;

  COUNT(*)
----------
      1358

SQL> truncate table sys.aud$;
truncate table sys.aud$
                   *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
```

Answer (score 0):

Connect as the admin user and run this rdsadmin command:

```
SQL> exec rdsadmin.rdsadmin_master_util.truncate_sys_aud_table;

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select count(*) from sys.aud$;

  COUNT(*)
----------
         0
```